# How to send an email for user and admin with two different parser templates on the same function, in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

how to send an email for user and admin with two different parser templates on the same function?

MY_MODEL:

```
function SendEmail($data,$email)
{
    $this->load->library('parser');
    $this->load->library('email');  

    // MESSAGE - ONE -> 2CLIENT!!!!!!
    $body = $this->parser->parse('../views/email_template_1', $data, true);

    //set from, to etc.
    $this->email->from('admin@xxx.com', 'ADMIN');
    $this->email->to('CLIENT@xxx');
    $this->email->subject('xxx');
    $this->email->message($body);
    $this->email->send();



    // MESSAGE - TWO -> 2ADMIN!!!!!!
    $bodyTwo = $this->parser->parse('../views/email_template_2', $data, true);

    //set from, to etc.
    $this->email->from('CLIENT@xxx.com', 'CLIENT NAME');
    $this->email->to('admin@xxx');
    $this->email->subject('xxx');
    $this->email->message($bodyTwo);
    $this->email->send();

}
```

Comment: What is the problem with your example?

Comment: Hi! This script are sending only one of blocks.

Comment: Any error messages? Try using echo $this->email->print_debugger(); and you can also try clearing variables between first and second run by using $this->email->clear()

Comment: I changed the protocol for "mail", and it worked !!
Thank you my friend! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the protocol for "mail", and it worked !!

Comment: Would you care to elaborate on this?  For future reference, a code snippet or a bit of a step-by-step on what you did to resolve your own issue would go a long way to both boost the community knowledge of your specific use case, and for others potentially looking for an answer with a similar use case.  It'd also keep your answer our of the Low Quality Post queue.  Just sayin'.